# How to set .realm file on realm

Tags: swift, realm

I'm developing an app using realm. then I want to initialize realm by a set .realm file on the app. It is initially on /Users/*****/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/~****~/Documents/default.realm/
I want the default.realm file on the app folder aligned with storyboard and ViewController.swift and other files. 
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a fileURL in the Realm init method

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(
    // Get the URL to the bundled file
    fileURL: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MyBundledData", withExtension: "realm"),
    // Open the file in read-only mode as application bundles are not writeable
    readOnly: true)

// Open the Realm with the configuration
let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
```

See the [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) for more information. There are more things you can configure [here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm/Configuration.html#/s:10RealmSwift0A0C13ConfigurationV7fileURL10Foundation0E0VSgvp) too.

**Important note:** See the comment in the code above:

> Open the file in read-only mode as application bundles are not writeable

To have the realm file sitting in your bundle, you would not be able to write to it, it would be read only. If you want to ship a pre-filled database with your app you can do this in your bundle but if you want it to be writeable you would need to copy it to the documents directory of your app on first launch and then use the version in that directory instead.

resources/files that you add in xcode and include in the 'copy bundle resources' in the build settings are included in your bundle. The bundle is not writeable. To ship a file with your app that you need to be writeable would need to be moved to a suitable folder. usually the app documents folder.

Comment: you should normally use .path instead of url string. `defaultRealmPath.absoluteString` should be `defaultRealmPath.path` but that wont be causing your issue currently. from what I can see if you run this on a device/simulator that hasn't already go the app on it should work. are you getting any errors logged? Sorry I cannot access chat from my current network

Comment: Sorry I was hanging on the chat. I tried the solution then I got no error. but I cannot see any data on preset.realm. the db is blank.

Comment: need to make sure that the db in the bundle has records in, try loading that one specifically (maybe read only) so that you can verify

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: The answer is my actual answer above. pass it a configuration and path

Comment: Nothing has changed.

Comment: well if you are passing it the path to the bundle's realm file than you have saved/exported an empty realm file.

Comment: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "preset", withExtension: "realm") means /Appname/preset.realm/ right?

Comment: we seem to be going in circles here as we are back to how to read a file from the bundle which is in my answer above and where we started with this question. In order to read a file from the bundle it needs to be in the project and you need to select 'copy items if needed' when dragging it into the project. Then check build settings > build rules > copy bundle resources. check this file is listed there so it is copied during build/archiving. Once you have this confirmed in the bundle. program defensively. there is no point in saying no still not working. we need to work out why.

Comment: so by programming defensively. things like `guard fileManager.fileExists(bundlepath or whatever) else { print("[DEBUG] - File not found in bundle") return }` so at any point of failure you know WHY it failed and we can go from there. if this passes then you know that the file actually exists at this path and you can then use it/read from it. and you can advise here... file exists in bundle, I can access and copy it but no records are found. then you limit the possibilities step by step.

Comment: I follow your guidance and I got no error. But data I set doesn't affect on my app. It create zero data file on here /Users/myUserName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/**‌​**8/data/Containers/‌​‌​Data/Application/***‌​**/Documents/default‌​.realm

Comment: then your copy function must be failing? or file already exists from previous attempts?

Comment: I got an error "Fatal error: A Realm Configuration must specify a path or an in-memory identifier." I didn't add realm file on build phrases

Comment: pass it the path, like in my answer above.

Comment: Do you successfully get data on my app from git?

Comment: I am on a secure network/laptop, so I cannot download the project here.  you should be able to do it yourself with the code I have seen. update your question with details on how you put the data in the preset.realm file

Comment: I put the data by using realm browser. Seems like every time I restart and build the app, it generate new default.realm file. and ignore the realm db that I put

Comment: anyways, it's night in Tokyo, so I will continue tomorrow. Thank you for everything.