# Swift: How to migrate custom Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am attempting to do migration on my custom Realm file. Note that in this project, I have two custom realm files on top of the default realm file, a `Photo.realm` and a `Transport.realm`. I have included a new attribute to the Photo object like so:

```
class Photo: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id: String? = nil
    @objc dynamic var secret: String? = nil
    @objc dynamic var server: String? = nil
    @objc dynamic var farm: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var imageData: Data? = nil
    @objc dynamic var tranport: Transport? //Newly added attribute
}
```

And would like to migrate. I have read the docs and since I am migrating on a custom realm file, I modified the code and added them to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` like so:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let defaultConfig = Realm.Configuration()

    if let fileURL = defaultConfig.fileURL {
        let photoRealmFileURL = fileURL.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("Photo.realm")
        let photoMigrationConfig = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: photoRealmFileURL, schemaVersion: 1, migrationBlock: { (migration, oldSchemaVersion) in
            if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {

            }
        }, objectTypes: [Photo.self])

        do {
            let _ = try Realm(configuration: photoMigrationConfig)
        } catch let error {
            print("Migration Error", error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }

    return true
}
```

At my HomeController, I initiate my realms like so:

```
class HomeController: UICollectionViewController {

    var photoRealm = try! Realm()
    var transportRealm = try! Realm()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupRealm()
    }

    fileprivate func setupRealm() {
        let defaultConfig = Realm.Configuration()

        if let fileURL = defaultConfig.fileURL {
            let photoRealmFileURL = fileURL.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("Photo.realm")
            let photoConfig = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: photoRealmFileURL, objectTypes: [Photo.self])

            let transportRealmFileURL = fileURL.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("Transport.realm")
            let tranportConfig = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: transportRealmFileURL, objectTypes: [Transport.self])

            do {
                photoRealm = try Realm(configuration: photoConfig)
                transportRealm = try Realm(configuration: tranportConfig)

                let cars = Transport()
                cars.name = "cars"

                let planes = Transport()
                planes.name = "planes"

                try transportRealm.write {
                    transportRealm.add(cars)
                    transportRealm.add(planes)
                }

            } catch let error {
                print("Error setting Realm", error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

With this, I am thrown the error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error:
>   Error Domain=io.realm Code=10 "Migration is required due to the
>   following errors:
>   - Property 'Photo.tranport' has been added." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Migration is required due to the
>   following errors:
>   - Property 'Photo.tranport' has been added., Error Code=10}

I suppose it's clear that the migration is not done properly. As I am migrating a custom realm and not the default realm, the docs are not quite clear how to properly do one.

Answer (score 0):

You can migrate your realm database by checking the schema version you want to update. and passing configuration to the default
configuration of the realm.

Add these lines of code into your appDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions Method. Just after your realm configuration and do the necessary changes to it.

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(
  // Set the new schema version. This must be greater than the previously used
  // version (if you've never set a schema version before, the version is 0).
  schemaVersion: 1,

  // Set the block which will be called automatically when opening a Realm with
  // a schema version lower than the one set above
  migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in

    if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
     // Add your class name where you have added new property 'tranport'.
      migration.enumerate(Photo.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
        newObject?["tranport"] = "Your value"
      }    
    }
  }
) 
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
```

Comment: Do I use defaultConfiguration even when I'm migrating a custom realm file?

Comment: yes, you need to pass your custom configuration to the default configuration. See the last line of code

Comment: I have tried your code, it successfully migrates but its making the `Photo.realm` the default realm. What I want to achieve is separation, whatever modifications to `Photo.realm` will happen on `Photo.realm`.

Comment: @Koh Great!!! Please follow this stack answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50462866/3278326